# Typescript definition files and extending external types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend one of my own types from an external type.

Since I don't really know what I'm doing I am putting these in the global.d.ts file.

Previous to doing this I have been importing types into every typescript file in my project which seems wrong and messy (30 import lines on the top of every file).

global.d.ts file works when I just have my code in it

```
// successfully can use this anywhere
interface IPerson {
   name: string
}
```

Where my understanding stops is what if I have a type that needs to extend one that's external.

(For example I'm going to try to extend the Redux action type).

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/redux/index.d.ts" />

interface IPerson {
  name: string
}

// even with the reference typescript 'cannot find name Action'
interface PersonAction extends Action {
   person?: IPerson
}
```

I can successfully get typescript to stop complaining that it can't find 'name Action' if I change the file to this

```
import * as Redux from 'redux';

interface IPerson {
  name: string
}

interface PersonAction extends Redux.Action {
  person?: IPerson
}
```

Except now every file that uses IPerson can no longer find it.  I don't understand why.  Anytime I add an import to a declaration file it breaks everything else, but fixes the declaration file.

What am I doing wrong here?  I'm looking for a place I can put all my types, if there's a better way to get typescript to recognize my types I'm open to other options.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `export` the interface from your module:

```
import * as Redux from 'redux';

export interface IPerson {
  name: string
}

export interface PersonAction extends Redux.Action {
  person?: IPerson
}
```

and then `import` the same at the place of usage:

```
import {IPerson, PersonAction} from 'your-module'
```

P.S. Though it is not a problem, you might want to [loose the 'I' from the name of interfaces](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines).